What is the speed of 1.32 Vmd?

*Aeroplane CL/CD polar curve
 (Image Source: Principles of flight. ATPL ground training series - Author: CAE Oxford Aviation Academy (UK) Limited 2014)
I’m studying Flight Mechanics in my textbook and I can’t figure out the speed of 1.32 Vmd.
I know that Vmd is the minimum drag speed. So, 1.32 Vmd is Vmd * 1.32, but why, according to the screenshot, does this speed have a lower CL and CD?
And where can such a speed be applied?
If someone can help me with this, I would be grateful to you.

Thank you!

I'm guessing it's a rule of thumb for maximum range speed for jet aircraft but have not been able to find the derivation. It's interesting that 1.32 is the reciprocal of the ratio of Vmp (minimum power required for propeller aircraft) over Vmd.

With regards to lower CD, remember that does not imply lower D, since qbar will be about 74% higher at 1.32Vmd than at Vmd.

I suppose you are analysing an airplane with a jet engine. If we consider the usual approximation for the drag coefficient of the entire airplane as being:
$C_d=C_{d_0}+kC²_l$
and we equate the power requested to win that drag with the power available from the engine(s), then we get that:

the speed for best loiter (aka endurance) corresponds to minimum drag (aka best L/D) and it is given by $V_{loiter}=V_{MD}=\sqrt{\frac{2W}{\rho S}\sqrt{\frac{k}{C_{d_0}}}}$

the speed for best range corresponds to 0.866 best L/D and it is given by $V_{range}=\sqrt{\frac{2W}{\rho S}\sqrt{\frac{3k}{C_{d_0}}}}$ which is $\sqrt{\sqrt{3}}=1.32$ times bigger than the previous $V_{MD}$; 1.32 is just the value given in your plot.



Another way of looking at the chart is to put Angle of Attack on the Coefficient of Lift axis.
Higher up represents higher AoA and lower airspeed, hence Vmp and Cl max "above" L/D max and 1.32 V md "below".
Using the lift equation Lift = Area × Density × coefficient of lift × Velocity$^2$, we see higher velocity means lower AoA for the same lift.
AoA is (linearly) part of the coefficient of lift, with the other part being the shape (lifting characteristics) of the airfoil itself.
1.32 V md would therefor be a cruise airspeed for maximum range.
